# Jquery Ui autocomplete get city from only one country

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

[Please visit my fiddle 1st](http://jsfiddle.net/5HcWK/)

I am using jquery Ui auto-complete there, I want the dropdown only display(trigger) cities from a single country (like Bangladesh). How can I get that?

Here is the JavaScript approach:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".city" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    name_startsWith: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                            value: item.name
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to pass country code in your url. e.g. `http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?&country=BD'

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5HcWK/2/)

**Updated js:**

```
$(function() {
        $( ".city" ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?&country=BD",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: {
                        featureClass: "P",
                        style: "full",
                        maxRows: 12,
                        name_startsWith: request.term
                    },
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
                            return {
                                label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                                value: item.name
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: nice and fast answer!!